# QRegex not identifing "\n"

Tags: c++, qregexp

My program get configuration from comandline. the comandline is like this:
"mapPath=Some_Path_Over_Here\npluginsPath=Other_Path_Over_Here\n"
please notice the "\n" in the middle and in the end.

my cose is:

```
QString config("mapPath=Some_Path_Over_Here\npluginsPath=Other_Path_Over_Here\n")
QRegExp reg("mapPath=(.*)\\npluginsDir=(.*)\\n");
```

but when I write

```
reg.indexIn(config)
```

the result is -1.

It is important to say that I my program is both for linux and windows.
I think what is causing the problem is the "\n".. I dont know how to handle it. help please?

Comment: You try to match strings containing `Dir` while your example string has `Path`. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes sorry.. I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

`config` contains two line-feed characters (ASCII `0x0A`, written in C++ literals as `\n`), but you're trying to match them against a regular expression `\n` (two characters, ASCII `0x5C 0x6E`, written in C++ literals as `\\n`). This can't work - change the regex to just `\n` as well.

Bear in mind that turning `\n` into a newline charcter is the job of the C++ parser; regular expressions don't do that.